# NSXMLParser parse error 65 in HTML

Tags: ios, xml, html-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am attempting to use `NSXMLParser` to parse an HTML file that I believe to be XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /foo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
…
```

the parsing is failing quite early

```
2013-08-23 13:40:00.413 Foo[61787:c07] -[DirectoryListingParserDelegate parser:parseErrorOccurred:] Line 1 Column 52 Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=65 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65.)"
```

error 65 is `NSXMLParserSpaceRequiredError` is occurring on line 1, column 52

Is there something wrong in the DOCTYPE line being returned by a common Apache server?

Is the `/EN` not wanted by the parser?